# How to use app check in react-native after enabling play-integrity in firebase?

Tags: android, reactjs, firebase, react-native

I'm trying to integrate firebase phone auth in react-native for (android/windows), and already enabled App-check with play integrity in firebase. I already installed all important package of react-native-firebase. but in their docs it's not clearly mentions how to use app-check. My app is only working on test-phone numbers that I added in firebase phone auth. If I'm using real number it's show this error :
`Error: [auth/missing-client-identifier] This request is missing a valid app identifier, meaning that neither SafetyNet checks nor reCAPTCHA checks succeeded. Please try again, or check the logcat for more details. NativeFirebaseError: [auth/missing-client-identifier] This request is missing a valid app identifier, meaning that neither SafetyNet checks nor reCAPTCHA checks succeeded. Please try again, or check the logcat for more details.`

please help me to resolve this issue.
I try to resolve it, but reCaptcha is not available for android in firebase. for app-check there's only 2 options ( SaftyNet and play intrigrety) I used play intrigrety because saftynet is deppericated. I don't know they don't mentions in erorr about play intrigrety.

Again help me coders, I'm stuck.

I tried all the docs from firebase but unable to figure out how to add app-check in react-native app.